# Что такое dependent handle?

Tags: .net, утечка-памяти

На странице из msdn ["Analyze .NET Framework memory issues"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn342825.aspx) перечислены 10 типов корневых ссылок, но их описание тавтологично.

Один из типов - Dependent Handle - описан как "A dependent object from the object handle table." Что же это такое?

Comment: Вот тут вроде бы есть объяснение: https://github.com/terrajobst/experimentation/blob/master/Documentation/ClrRuntime.md#dependent-handles

Comment: @VladD спасибо. Значит, dependent handle - на самом деле не корень и утечку памяти вызвать не может... Жаль.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Жаль, что не помогло, но с другой стороны хорошо, что выяснилось что-то новое и интересное.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как указано в приведенной VladD [статье](https://github.com/terrajobst/experimentation/blob/master/Documentation/ClrRuntime.md#dependent-handles), Dependent Handle - это особый тип ссылки с двумя параметрами - source и target, причем для source она ведет себя как слабая ссылка, а для target - как сильная, но с одним исключением: источником ссылки на target является не сама Dependent Handle, а source. Иными словами, в граф объектов добавляется дополнительная дуга.

Создаются такие ссылки через класс `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable<,>`, являющийся хеш-таблицей.

При этом, в отличии от обычных хеш-таблиц, даже построенных на слабых ссылках, ConditionalWeakTable не вызывает утечек памяти даже в случае наличия циклических ссылок, в чем можно убедиться вот такой проверкой:

```
class BigObject
{
    private static readonly ConditionalWeakTable<BigObject, BigObject> table = new ConditionalWeakTable<BigObject, BigObject>();
    private readonly byte[] arr = new byte[1024 * 1024];

    public BigObject()
    {
        table.Add(this, this);
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            new BigObject();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

После выполнения этого кода если бы в хеш-таблице использовались обычные слабые ссылки на ключи и сильные ссылки на значения - то для выполнения программы понадобилось бы 100 гигабайт памяти. Но этого не происходит.